# downloading from github returns '404 not found' plus wrong download size

Tags: r, github, download

I'm trying to download a .tif file from github using this code:

```
file1 <- "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif"

dir.create("data", showWarnings = FALSE)


if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file1))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://github.com/lime-n/data/blob/main/modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif", file1),
                file.path("data", file1), mode = "wb")
}
```

However, it returns this error:

> trying URL 'https://github.com/lime-n/data/blob/main/modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tifmodis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif'
> Error in download.file(paste0("https://github.com/lime-n/data/blob/main/modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif",  :
> cannot open URL 'https://github.com/lime-n/data/blob/main/modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tifmodis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In download.file(paste0("https://github.com/lime-n/data/blob/main/modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif",  :
> cannot open URL 'https://github.com/lime-n/data/blob/main/modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tifmodis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

any way to overcome this?

**EDIT**:

thanks to @MrFlick, the previous problem was solved.

However, when I download the file its not in the original size. It goes from 8.5mb when downlaoded manually from github to ~85kb when using the corrected version of the code above:

```
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file1))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://github.com/lime-n/data/blob/main/", file1),
                file.path("data", file1), mode = "wb")
}
```

I try reading this into a `raster` as you can imagine, it does not work.

Comment: You seem to be pasting the "modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif" file name into the URL twice. Did you mean just `paste0("https://github.com/lime-n/data/blob/main/", file1)`?

Comment: @MrFlick That fixes the problem! although, I've come to face a new problem. On downloading the .tif, I cannot read it into r using `raster`, because it `cannot create a rasterlayer from this`. On top of this, when downloaded, its only 8.5kb, and the original file when downloaded from github is 8.5mb. Why might this be happening? and a solution to the first problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL still isn't right. The 84K you are downloading is the html of the GitHub page, not the binary file itself. You need:

```r
if (!file.exists(file.path("data", file1))) {
  download.file(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/", file1),
                file.path("data", file1), mode = "wb")
}
#. trying URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lime-n/data/main/modis_mcd12q1_umd_2010.tif'
#> Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 8791730 bytes (8.4 MB)
#> downloaded 8.4 MB
```